# Make SVG Text unselectable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

I have a svg with some text

**EDIT: This is all the elements on my svg in order to accomplish the effect I need**

```
<g id="top">
<path ....>
</g>
<g id="bottom">
<path ....>
</g>
<g id="boxes">
<rect ....>
</g>
<g id="txt">
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 50 30)" class="svgtxt">TEXT</text>
</g>
```

Currently if I hover the mouse over the "TEXT" word I am able to select it.

I am trying to find a way to make it not to be selectable, using CSS, JQuery (as follows) but nothing seems to work. I could not find anything similar either.

**CSS**

```
.svgtxt{
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select:none;
  -khtml-user-select:none;
  -moz-user-select:none;
  -ms-user-select:none;
  -o-user-select:none;
  user-select:none;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('#txt text').onmousedown = function() { return false; };
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you put another transparent, or very nearly transparent, element above it in the z-order?

Comment: Works just fine for me -> **https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/72LvL8n6/**

Comment: Adding an inline style (to the text element) of `-webkit-user-select:none;` works for me in Chrome - might also want a `cursor:default;`

Comment: I edited my code and included the svg elements. None works with what I have.

Comment: You have on example with jsfiddle?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You could disable `pointer-events` if you don't need any interaction:

> The pointer-events attribute allows authors to control whether or when an element may be the target of a mouse event. This attribute is used to specify under which circumstance (if any) a mouse event should go "through" an element and target whatever is "underneath" that element instead.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pointer-events

```
.svgText {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked just fine with my code and that I needed to accomplish.

Comment: I found this does not work on android. After clicking an element with an `onclick` in it the text selection indicators appear and the 'Select All' balloon with it..

Answer (score 39):

It works for me this way:

```
svg text{
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   -moz-user-select: none;
   -ms-user-select: none;
   user-select: none;
}
```

If you still face problem in touch devices you could use(this is just a trick):

```
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color:  rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
```

Comment: I am using React and creating SVG's texts dynamically and this is the only answer that worked (using the style attribute directly).